# JBOSS : all arraylist elements pointing to the same object

Tags: java, jboss, taglib

I am storing all the instances of a taglib from its `doStartTag()` method into an arraylist in following manner:

```
    repeatTag.setTD(this);
```

And in the `setTD()` method have the following code for adding the instance to arrayList.

```
    public List<TDTag> tdlist;
    public List<TDTag> getTDList(){
       return tdlist;
    }
    public void setTD(TDTag tdTag){
       tdlist.add(tdTag);
    }
```

Here all the elements in tdlist is having the last instance of `TDTag`. The above code is working fine in weblogic and websphere. Issue only in JBOSS. Why is the behavior in JBOSS, different from weblogic? Where could I have been doing mistake?

Comment: This is not a duplicate but is very much similar

Comment: Finally found the issue, in JBOSS 7, tag pooling is enabled by default and same instance of `TDTag` was added into arraylist with new values. Hence all elements point to the same object with the values of last execution of TDTag.